# Trying to understand Python and all its moving parts - What is the difference between Tkinter and Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, event-handling, tkinter

I have a school project where my team needs to build a board game. We want to use Python based on all the good things we have heard.  I have been researching MVC frameworks and came across Django (its part of my installation on Pydev). I have a Mac, fyi.

I have also been looking up Tkinter but cant seem to understand what the difference is between Django and Tkinter.  Why would you use one over the other?  I understand that Django is for Web Development.  And I think I understand that Tkinter is for building GUI's right?

The board game will have multiple players who should all get updated when one of the players makes a move.

Can any of you point me to where I should be looking online based on what I am trying to do?  I am not looking for code, but just the right website with some good documentation and tutorials that will help me out.  Thanks again, Mash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if your game has a GUI, then you have two options:

1. Use a desktop client. This will require Tkinter. In this case, I think it's better not to use Django. Use some other lightweight networking library if you want a network play. [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) for example.
2. Use a web client. For this, you can use HTML/CSS for the GUI. Django is a better choice for this one. Tkinter is not needed.

Personally, I would go for no. 2, since I happen to have a friend who's into graphic design, and I can, uh... "persuade" him to do the HTML/CSS part. I'm not an evil person. Honest!

On a serious note though, since you're building a game, why not consider [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/)?

Comment: thanks this is the kind of feedback I was seeking.  I will surely look into pygame and twisted.  Ive been messing around with Tkinter and am very impressed with how easy it is to build and modify widgets...kinda fun!

Comment: It doesnt look like pygame supports Python 3.3.2 for Mac OS X Lion!  What a bummer.  Im thinking of reverting back to the default Python 2.7.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Is Python 3.x the default installation in OSX Lion?

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter is a GUI library (for desktop applications) and Django is for web development. Both are completely different and in fact it is useless to compare them even.